# Eclipse crashes in particuar (weird) moments

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have eclipse 3.8 on Debian testing and it always crashes in some moments. Two examples:

- when i go to project properties and click Cancel
- when i try to install eclox plugin, and click Finish (accept agreement)

some information from crash when clicking Cancel:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff7d212b4c8, pid=470, tid=140702795228928
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b31) (build 1.7.0_51-b31)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x194c8]  g_object_get_qdata+0x18
#
```

Comment: I know it is not very popular, but did you try to run the same eclipse with oracle jdk instead? I also experience some problems in Ubuntu and I run it with oracle jdk flawless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of this step

1.cd to your eclipse directory and clean using terminal

```
./eclipse -clean
```

2.Restart your machine